# How to parameterize the token value authorization on the header in golang

Tags: json, go, https, cyber-ark

I'm a newbie to go and trying to make a call to cyberark to grab a secret and trying to figure out on how to parametrize the token value.This value is derived from another rest API call that will happen before this API call. So I wanted to pass that response from the other API call and pass in here as token. Below is my code; I tried creating a variable for the token response I get from the other API call to be able to be used here, but running into different formatting errors like newline in string error and so on.

```
package main

    import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "io/ioutil"
    )

   func main() {

    url := "https://secrets.com/password"
     method := "GET"

     client := &http.Client {
     }
      req, err := http.NewRequest(method, url, nil)

      if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
      return
     }
      req.Header.Add("Accept-Encoding", "base64")
      req.Header.Add("Authorization", "Token token=\"eyJwcm90ZWN0ZWQiOiJleU\"")
      req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json")

     res, err := client.Do(req)
      if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
      return
     }
     defer res.Body.Close()

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
     if err != nil {
      fmt.Println(err)
      return
     }
    fmt.Println(string(body))
   }
```

Comment: If I assume the code you pasted is a direct copy, then perhaps you are getting an error like `expected ';', found ':'` because your `url` variable is not using a string. `url := "https://secrets.com/password"`

Comment: That was a typo while formatting the code in here.My original code has it.

Comment: [Looking at this])https://docs.cyberark.com/conjur-enterprise/13.0/en/Content/Developer/Conjur_Auth_REST_APIs.htm) it seems like the correct format is probably `Authorization: Token token=eyJwcm90ZWN0ZWQiOiJleU`